# Google Analytics integration with Tealium

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, tealium

I am working on Tealium integration with Sitecore and I have installed Tealium Tag Manager Sitecore connector, as well as I have aslo done all the configuration which is needed to use Tealium.

After enabling Google Analytics service from Tealium my website keep loading.

Does anyone have any experience with Sitecore Tealium Connector?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also faced the same issue.
In my Scenario it was a network proxy issue and i tried the same thing in open network and it worked for me.

Please check your network settings if there is any proxy.

Comment: Thanks Arpit for quick response, Yes we do use proxy settings to use internet locally. Let me check same thing in our dev environment.